# Deploy an interactive dynamic interface with some complex code behind

Tags: interface, user-interface, deployment, cloud-deploy

This question might have been discussed in bits and pieces already, but I couldn't find a coherent conversation about what are the best practices and strategies for deploying a moderately complex *Mathematica* code that

1. uses other user-defined functions (sometimes from other notebooks)
2. uses packages (located locally)
3. contains dynamic-based user interface (nothing fancy -- few sliders, output windows, buttons -- really a small input-output panel, but with lots of calculations behind the scene)

Under *deploying* I understand here that it can be run on a completely (or almost) fresh machine (read internet cafe), preferably also without a need to install a third party software? Or anything as close to this as possible.

I don't really care if the code is visible/protected or not, but I want the dynamic interface to be the main part a user sees when they open it.

CDF player is not a good option, simply because it is not supported on Chrome, so it is not really a useful method.

I understand it is general enough, and I can make up some minimal code, but I am not sure it would be useful before we understand the general idea how to pre-process such working environment and package it for the deployment.

I suspect there is no easy answer, so it would be great to learn what is the general approach to this.

Comment: Do you want to discuss each deployment type or compare pros and cons of each? Because for the former it is a chapter long answer for every type if methods need to be outlined.

Comment: @Kuba i'd say not every type, i just want to see what is a general guideline for a moderate complexity code to be reliably published. I suspect it has to be Wolfram Cloud, but I might not know something obviously more useful. Generally, I want to learn what people use and find useful.

Comment: Did you get some answers or ideas?